# Given a dictionary how can I check if two of its keys are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have one dictionary:

```
dict_one={'a':'the quick brown fox.','b':'the quick brown fox.', 'c':'good night guys',...,'n':'hey there'}
```

how can I check if key `a` and key `b` string values are the same and add a new key to the dictionary `equals` to the dictionary showing me if they are different or equal values (True/False)?

```
dict_one={'a':'the quick brown fox.','b':'the quick brown fox.', 'c':'good night guys',...,'n':'hey there', 'equals':True}
```

I tried to:

```
for i,j in dict_one.iteritems():
 if (a==b):
     return 'True'
 else:
      return 'False'
```

Comment: You should read about python dictionaries https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. It looks like you just need to access the dictionary values and compare them. `dict_one["equals"] = dict_one["a"] == dict_one["b"]`

Comment: Note that your code produces a syntax error (`...`) and two name errors (`a` and `b`), and `'c'` and `'n'` in `dict_one` are unused. I mention cause when asking a question, it's best to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask two different questions:

> Given a dictionary how can I check if two of its keys are the same?

A dict by definition can't have duplicate keys.

> How can I check if key `a` and key `b` string values are the same and add a new key to the dictionary `equals` if they are different or equal values (True/False)?

This compares the values of keys `a` and `b` and assigns the result to key `equals`:

```
dict_one['equals'] = dict_one['a'] == dict_one['b']
```

Comment: which other data structure should I use for this comparison?

Comment: @anon Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

So from your example you only want to check whether any two **values** (not keys as you write in your question title) are the same, but you don't care which ones those are. The fastest and easiest way of doing that is probably

```
len(set(dict_one.values())) < len(dict_one)
```

This converts all values of the dict into a set which, if there are any duplicates, will contain fewer items than the original dict. So the above code will return true if any values in the dict are duplicated and it will run in O(n) rather than O(n^2) which the solution you attempted would have taken.

Edit: for completeness:

```
dict_one['equals'] = len(set(dict_one.values())) < len(dict_one)
```

will set the entry in the dict as you requested

Answer (score -1):

use `dict.update()`

```
dict_one={'a':'the quick brown fox.','b':'the quick brown fox.', 'c':'good night guys','n':'hey there'}

dic = {'equal':True} if dict_one['a']==dict_one['b'] else {'equal':False}

dict_one.update(dic)
print(dict_one)
```

output

```
dict_one={'a':'the quick brown fox.','b':'the quick brown fox.', 'c':'good night guys',...,'n':'hey there'}
```

Comment: I think here is missing the new key, saying that `a` and `b` are equal

Comment: You can shorten this down to just `dict_one['equals'] = dict_one['a'] == dict_one['b']`

Comment: @anon i just created his final output ,what he want

Comment: @wjandrea thanks , didn't know we can do this way also

Comment: @anon you can do `assert dict_one['a']==dict_one['b']`